# How to visualise truncated trapezohedra in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, polyhedra

This wikipedia page has some interesting polyhedra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_trapezohedron.

[image: Truncated Hexagonal Trapezohedron]

I have not been able to find them in the PolyhedronData list of mathematica or on Dmccooey. http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/index.html

My question is how can I visualise and analyse these polyhedra in Mathematica? Ideally I would like to obtain the vertex and face information in some way.

My initial thought was to start with

> > PolyhedronData[{"Trapezohedron", 6}]

Followed by slicing the top and bottom off. However, I am not sure how to do this and how to ensure I am left with 12 regular pentagons and two regular hexagons.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using @halmir's truncation method and George Hart's canonicalize function (https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2012/):

```
face2edges[face_] := MapThread[Sort[{#1, #2}] & , {face, RotateLeft[face]}]; 
f2e[f_] := Union @@ face2edges /@ f
closest[{P1_,P2_}]:=With[{L=P2-P1},P1-(L . P1 L)/L . L]
recenter[v_, e_] := 
  With[{centroid = Plus @@ closest /@ Map[v[[#1]] & , e, {2}]/Length[e]}, 
   (#1 - centroid & ) /@ v]
tangentify[v_, e_] := 
   Module[{newV = v, t, c}, Scan[(t = closest[v[[#1]]]; 
        c = 0.5*(1 - Sqrt[t . t])*t; newV[[#1[[1]]]] += c; 
        newV[[#1[[2]]]] += c; ) & , e]; newV]
        
unit[x_] := With[{mag2 = x . x}, If[mag2 != 0, x/Sqrt[mag2], x]]

cross[{ax_, ay_, az_}, {bx_, by_, bz_}] := 
  {ay*bz - az*by, az*bx - ax*bz, ax*by - ay*bx}
  
approxNormal[face_] := 
  unit[Plus @@ MapThread[unit[cross[#1 - #2, #2 - #3]] & , 
     {face, RotateLeft[face, 1], RotateLeft[face, 2]}]]
     
planarize[v_, f_] := 
  Module[{newV = v, faceXYZ, n, centroid}, 
   Scan[(faceXYZ = v[[#1]]; n = approxNormal[faceXYZ]; 
        centroid = Plus @@ faceXYZ/Length[faceXYZ]; 
        if[n . centroid < 0, n = -n]; 
        Scan[newV[[#1]] += 0.2*n . (centroid - v[[#1]])*n & , #1]; ) & , f]; 
    newV]
    
canonicalize[v_, f_] := 
  Module[{newV = N[v], e = f2e[f], oldV, maxChange}, 
   Do[oldV = newV; newV = tangentify[newV, e]; newV = recenter[newV, e]; 
      newV = planarize[newV, f]; maxChange = Max[Abs[oldV - newV]]; 
      If[maxChange < 10.^(-8), Break[]], {i, 80}]; 
    Print["Solved within ", maxChange]; newV]

tt2 = RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{3,3,-1.34}, {-3, -3, 1.34}], 
  PolyhedronData[{"Trapezohedron", 6}, "Polyhedron"]];

vtt2 = PolyhedronCoordinates[tt2];
ftt2 = Part[#, 1] & /@ MeshCells[tt2, 2];

Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick}], 
  Polygon /@ Map[vtt2[[#1]] & , ftt2, {2}], Black, Sphere[vtt2, 0.1]}]
  , PlotRange-> All, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Truncated Hexagonal Trapezohedron]

```
vcanon = canonicalize[vtt2, ftt2];

Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick}], 
  Polygon /@ Map[vcanon[[#1]] & , ftt2, {2}], Black, Sphere[vnew, 0.07]}]
  , PlotRange-> All, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Canonical Truncated Hexagonal Trapezohedron]

Answer (score 6):

truncate using RegionIntersection:

```
tt = RegionIntersection[Cube[3.4], 
  PolyhedronData[{"Trapezohedron", 6}, "Polyhedron"]]

Graphics3D[tt]
```

[image]
coordinates:

```
PolyhedronCoordinates[tt]
```

> {{0.470488, 0.814909, -1.7}, {0.940976,
> 0., -1.7}, {0.470488, -0.814909, -1.7}, {-0.470488, -0.814909, 
> -1.7}, {-0.940976, 0., -1.7}, {-0.470488, 0.814909, -1.7}, {-0.814909,
> 0.470488, 1.7}, {-0.814909, -0.470488,
> 1.7}, {-2.22045*10^-16, -0.940976, 1.7}, {0.814909, -0.470488,
> 1.7}, {0.814909, 0.470488, 1.7}, {2.22045*10^-16, 0.940976,
> 1.7}, {-1.43145, 0.826446, 0.258819}, {-0.826446,
> 1.43145, -0.258819}, {-1.65289,
> 0., -0.258819}, {-0.826446, -1.43145, -0.258819}, {-1.43145, 
> -0.826446, 0.258819}, {1.43145, 0.826446, 0.258819}, {0.826446,
> 1.43145, -0.258819}, {0., 1.65289,
> 0.258819}, {0.826446, -1.43145, -0.258819}, {1.65289,
> 0., -0.258819}, {1.43145, -0.826446, 0.258819}, {0., -1.65289,
> 0.258819}}

face indices:

```
tt[[2]]
```

> {{13, 14, 6, 5, 15}, {5, 4, 16, 17, 15}, {12, 11, 19, 20,    21}, {22,
> 3, 2, 23, 24}, {9, 26, 22, 24, 10}, {23, 2, 1, 20,    19}, {16, 26, 9,
> 8, 17}, {12, 21, 14, 13, 7}, {6, 14, 21, 20,    1}, {10, 24, 23, 19,
> 11}, {16, 4, 3, 22, 26}, {17, 8, 7, 13,    15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
> {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}

```
Counts[Length /@ tt[[2]]]
```

> <|5 -> 12, 6 -> 2|>

Comment: This is great, thanks! Do you perhaps know how I can do the cut-off such that the pentagons are regular?

Comment: @PTeeuwen I don't think you can make one from this

Comment: Using your method I was able to make the pentagons resemble a regular pentagon a bit more: tt2 = RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{3,3,-1.34}, {-3, -3, 1.34}], 
  PolyhedronData[{"Trapezohedron", 6}, "Polyhedron"]]. But I think you are right about there not being a perfectly regular one. For my purposes this is what I was looking for regardless. Thank you!

Comment: For the face-indices I also noticed that faces = Part[#, 1] & /@ MeshCells[tt, 2] is working better for me. tt[[2]] is giving 26 as an index, even though there should only be 24 indices.

Comment: Lastly, George Hart's canonicalize function worked very nicely as well to create the final structure: https://www.georgehart.com/canonical/canonical-supplement.html